# set up a basic local server with ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, server, gulp, localhost

This is maybe a noobie question, but I am working on a Ruby project and now I have to serve some files from localhost for a couple of tests that need to read a webpage that is loaded locally. I am using `gulp` for that, but I would like to do it in Ruby. I found out about Rack but I can't wrap my head around it to do the very simple thing I want to do.

This is my folder structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── lib
│   └── page_reader.rb
├── spec
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── page_reader_spec.rb
└── gulpfile.js
```

What I have now in my `gulpfile.js` is:

```
var
  browsersync  = require('browser-sync').create(),
  gulp         = require('gulp')
;

gulp.task('server', function() {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './spec/fixtures/'
    },
    port:   4000,
    notify: false,
    open:   false
  });
});
```

Basically, I have an `index.html` inside `./spec/fixtures/` folder and I am using the `browser-sync` module to start a local server, then I make it point to the `fixtures`folder inside my tests folder. When I want to run the tests, I have to do:

```
$ gulp server
```

in one terminal, then go to `http://localhost:4000` to load the page against which I am running the tests, and then in another terminal do:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
```

to run the tests.

Is there a way to do what I am doing through `gulp` but using Ruby instead? I searched for a gem that worked in a similar way as the `browser-sync` module but couldn't find any. However I think there must be a way that is as simple as it is doing it with gulp. I can keep on doing it with `gulp`, as it works perfectly, but it feels weird to mix JavaScript and Ruby in this particular way and in this context.

Comment: What specific functionality of browser sync are you looking to include? Your question title suggests you're trying to just set up a static http server, which is simpler than what you're trying to do. Take a look at Selenium's ruby bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest answer I know:

```
cd spec/fixtures && ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 4000 .
```

That's courtesy of [Aaron Patterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178850/aaron-patterson) ([@tenderlove](https://twitter.com/tenderlove)), via [Gavin Kistner](http://phrogz.net/simplest-possible-ruby-web-server), [Ben Oakes](http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2013/09/13/ruby-simple-http-server-minimalist-rake/), and a cast of thousands. I love a good community. =]

Comment: Thank you, this worked and is exactly what I wanted!
And I can also use it with CI +1